# Безопасные запросы EXTRACT

Tags: java, jpa, criteriabuilder

В JPA можно получить год выполнив такой запрос

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR SYSDATE) FROM DUAL;
```

можно ли получить год с поле с помощью запросов `CriteriaBuilder` и `Predicate`;

Comment: напишите как вы пробовали это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно с помощью `CriteriaBuilder.function`:

```
filterApps = builder.equal(
            builder.function("TO_CHAR", Date.class,root.get("youDateColumn"), builder.literal("yyyy")), youYear);
    predicateList.add(filterApps);
```